# How to @Autowire scala objects in Spring

Tags: java, spring, scala, dependency-injection

Consider the following code:

**TimeSeries.scala**

```
trait TimeSeries {
   def someMethod()
}

object TimeSeries extends TimeSeries {
   def someMethod() = { new someOtherMethod() }
}
```

**META-INF/spring/series.xml**

```
<bean id="timeSeries" class="com.people.user.data.TimeSeries" />
```

**SomeService.java**

```
class SomeService
{
   @Autowired
   private TimeSeries timeSeries;

   TimeSeries.someMethod(); //Compile Time Error
}
```

The first thing to note here is `TimeSeries.scala` file is having `TimeSeries Object` so I assumed that it is having a class scope and so I can call its method directly by `TimeSeries.someMethod();` without instantiating it.

However, this is not the case. I am getting Compile Time Error on doing so.

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method `someMethod`
```

So I felt to introduce the @Autowiring so that Spring can auto instantiate it.
However, this isn't working either saying the error for:

`<bean id="timeSeries" class="com.people.user.data.TimeSeries" />`

The error is: `TimeSeries is an interface and not a class.`

I understood this and so changed the name of object class to be:

```
object TimeSeriesImpl extends TimeSeries {
       def someMethod() = { new someOtherMethod() }
    }
```

Also changed the spring XML:

`<bean id="timeSeries" class="com.people.user.data.TimeSeriesImpl" />`

But now getting error on instantiating the scala class.

It seems like Spring doesn't understood how to instantiate the Scala class with the above configurations.

Here is the LOG:

**LOG:**

```
Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception 
is     org.springframework.beans.
BeanInstantiationException: 
Could not instantiate bean class [com.people.user.data.TimeSeries]: 
No default constructor found; nested exception 
is  java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.people.user.
data.TimeSeries.<init>()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method `someMethod`

The problem is you can't call `TimeSeries.someMethod();` directly.

where,
TimeSeries is the scala object and `someMethod()` is the method on that object.

The correct way is:

`TimeSeries$ timeSeries = TimeSeries$.MODULE$;
timeSeries.someMethod();`